# Copy two sheets into new workbook as values, then save with todays date and close workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When using all the different examples that I've found on stackoverflow they give me a complex task that still requires a mouse click to confirm its ok to paste the data. I also am struggling to get the whole thing to operate in one section of VBA code.

```
Public Sub copySheets()
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim newWkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim newWks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sheets As Variant
Dim varName As Variant
'------------------------------------------------------------


'Define the names of worksheets to be copied.
sheets = VBA.Array("Analysis - London", "London - Commercial")


'Create reference to the current Excel workbook and to the destination workbook.
Set wkb = Excel.ThisWorkbook
Set newWkb = Excel.Workbooks.Add


For Each varName In sheets

    'Clear reference to the [wks] variable.
    Set wks = Nothing

    'Check if there is a worksheet with such name.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(VBA.CStr(varName))
    On Error GoTo 0


    'If worksheet with such name is not found, those instructions are skipped.
    If Not wks Is Nothing Then

        'Copy this worksheet to a new workbook.
        Call wks.Copy(newWkb.Worksheets(1))

        'Get the reference to the copy of this worksheet and paste
        'all its content as values.
        Set newWks = newWkb.Worksheets(wks.Name)
        With newWks
            Call .Cells.Copy
            Call .Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlValues)
        End With

    End If

Next
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=("C:\Users\\My stuff\Forecast" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & " Forecasting" & ".xlsm")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
  With newWks
        Call .Cells.Copy
        Call .Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlValues)
    End With
```

With

```
 Dim c as range
 For each c in newwks.usedrange
     c.formula = c.value
 next c
```